# iOS: Close keyboard when UITextField loses focus

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

How can I recognize that some other view was clicked while keyboard is opened and close the keyboard. The other view can be in a parent controller or some other controller presented on the screen.

Comment: How about when another controller is presented you on viewdiddisappear of parent controller call endediting on the view

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a tap gesture recognizer on the main view of the viewController. When it is tapped call `view.endEditing(true)`.

If you have other gesture recognizers and don't want to interfere with them, try settings up the tap recognizer, creating a reference to it (if doing it in a storyboard) and then in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` set the recognizer to enabled, and in `textFieldDidEndEditing` set it to disabled.

Code snippet just for good faith:

```
class FakeViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    private let viewTappedGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupGestureRecognizer()
    }

    private func setupGestureRecognizer() {
        viewTappedGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(viewWasTapped))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTappedGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func viewWasTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }


    // MARK: - TextField Delegate

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        viewTappedGestureRecognizer.enabled = true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        viewTappedGestureRecognizer.enabled = false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in your case you may have more then one viewController presented on the screen the best approach to handle this is to use `Notification Pattern`
to notify the current `Observer` (customView or a ViewControler) that its `textField`/`textView` (i.e. the current `firstResponder` i.e. keyboardshown) should `resignFirstResponder` (and dismiss keyboard).

***Register to observe any DismissKeyboardNeededNotification in BeginEditing on (TextField or TextView ):***

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissKeyboard) name:DismissKeyboardNeededNotification object:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

**Remove Observer to Notification( DismissKeyboardNeededNotification) in EndEditing**

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:DismissKeyboardNeededNotification object:nil];

}
```

**If the current ViewController get notified then simply it ask the textfield to resignFirstResponder to dismissKeyboard**

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard{

    [self.textField resignFirstResponder]; 
    //or if you have many textField/TextView find it resignFirstResponder
    //[self.textView1 isFirstResponder] then resignFirstResponder
}
```

from any viewController when a view is taped/selected (except UITextView or UITextView) just post the notification to ask to dismissKeyboard if needed, if a the keyboard is currently shown then one of your ViewController is observing that notification and it will handled.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:DismissKeyboardNeededNotification object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

note:this public string should to accessible to all VC :

```
 NSString* DismissKeyboardNeededNotification = @"DismissKeyboardNeededNotification";
```